# Insert Query for a PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert-query

I am using PHP and MySQL and I have run into a small problem. I have tried to research and figure out what to do, however, I just can't figure it out. I would appreciate any help. Here is my problem...

I have 3 SQL tables:

```
Customers
    cID (primaryKey)
    email
    name
    password
    ...etc.

Products
    pID (primaryKey)
    Pname
    Ptype

CustomerRequests
    requestID(primarykey)
    cID (foreign key references customer table)
    pID (foreign key references products table)
    quantityRequested
```

I have an HTML form that I am processing with PHP. This is like the request form, so the user logs in and fills in the request form. The fields on this form are like:

selecting product name, selecting quantity etc. This is done for e.g. `$quantity=$_POST['quantity']`... so basically the form data is stored inside the variables.

Now, here is the part that I'm stuck on. How do I carry out a SQL `INSERT` query so that the database knows what the `cID` and `pID` are? I.e. What the foreign key values are?

For example:

```
$insert = mysql_query(INSERT INTO CustomerRequests VALUES ('THIS WOULD BE BLANK AS ITS AUTOINCREMENTED PROMARY KEY FOR REQUEST ID','HOW WOULD I GET THE cID AUTOMATICALLY HERE','HOW WOULD I GET THE pID HERE','".$quantity."'))
```

The query stores the user input into the database using an `INSERT` query. However, since the customerID and productID are foreign keys in a different table how do i write the PHP query?

Thanks for the help and please get back to me if you need further information.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think you have a problem. The `cID` should be known because the customer is logged in. The `pID` should be known because your form should be using a dropdown list of products with the `pID` being used as the `value`.

Then it's a simple matter of doing an `INSERT` using those values, i.e.

```
<select id="product">
    <option value="pid001">Product One</option>
    <option value="pid002">Product Two</option>
    ... etc. ...
</select>
```

In other words, these values are all known *before* they hit your form.

Don't match product names with ID's after the fact; that's just adding extra work. If you have a value available then you should use it. Your form should already contain the association.

Create the dropdown based on a `SELECT` query from your Products table. Use the `pID` for the `value` and the `pName` for the content. That way, the data sent in the form is the foreign key you need in your `INSERT`.

```
<?php
    /* 
     * $arrProducts is the result from a query like
     * SELECT * FROM Products;
     */
    print '<select id="products">';
    foreach ($arrProducts as $arrProduct) {
        printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $arrProduct['pID'], $arrProduct['pName']);
    }
    print '</select>';
?>
```

Similarly, when you log your user in, get their `cID` and insert it into the session.

One other note, **cease from using PHP's `mysql_` family of functions**. These are deprecated and due to be removed from a future release. They are prone to SQL Injection. You should be using either `mysqli_` or PDO in your application. Both offer parameterized queries and prepared statement.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your swift reply. Sorry this is what my form is like
`<select name="productN">
<option value="grapes">grapes</option>
<option value="banana">banana</option>
 etc..
</select>`
so I am a little confused... Because, when the user registers I create a session $_SESSION['username'] = $username; where the $username is the value received from the login form... So I dont know what to do exactly. Since, when the user logs in it creates a session how would I find out what the cID is? 

Thanks.

Comment: Since you have a table with product information, you should populate your dropdowns with that data, doncha think? If you insist on going down this road, then you will need to `JOIN` both the Customers and Products table into the `INSERT` query. You're just making your life difficult.

Comment: okay sure so.. as my products table like I mentioned has ... ProductID, ProductName, ProductTYpe.. u think my form should be like: <select name="productN"> <option value="1">grapes</option> <option value="2">banana</option> etc.. </select> where 1 represents Pid for grapes in the table? 
Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it. Think of the ID's as data your code needs to understand, and the content of the dropdown as data your users need to understand. Don't mix them in weird ways.

Comment: The product table only shows them 3 fields mentioned... the productRequest table should link which customer made the request i.e. cid, the product id from the product table, and then the other values I know how to get using $_POST variables. ... I am so lost with this insert query :'( been working on it for hours!

Comment: Okay buddy this is what I have done.... My products table looks like this...pid(PKey), pName, pType.... now the drop down form for the products is like this...   <select name="productN"> <option value="1">grapes</option> <option value="2">banana</option> etc.. </select> so this corresponds to my product table .. where the entries are 1,grapes,fruit ... 2,banana,fruit...etc.. so now i can do something like $fruidID=$_POST['productN'] so the selected product will be stored inside the variable i.e. if user selects grapes it will be $fruidid=1.. Now I need to just use $fruitid in the insert query

Comment: and figure out a way to get the cid..when the user logs in... !! I think I might be getting somewhere ur comment about the ID's as data your code needs and content as user readability makes sense.. You sir are a genius!

Comment: Can I get some green checky love for my genius? :)

Comment: yes sure thanks:) I also wanted to ask another thing.. Say I have a php website Im making... what I need to do is implement like a resource allocation algoritm. Let me explain... you might have like 3 sellers and 1 buyer.. so that sellerA is selling 1 kilo of carrots for £1...sellerB is selling 1.3Kilo of carrots for £1.10 customerA wants 1 kilo of carrorts fm the lowest supplier... how would you allocate such resorces? do you have any idea where you can point me in the right direction? I believe I would need to code and algorithm in ph p  that would do some sort of allocating of products?Ty:)

Comment: You should ask that as a new question on SO. :)

Comment: Sorry what is SO? I am new to this site still:) okay just got it stack overflow lol... sorry

Answer (score 1):

I think you should retrieve the product and customer IDs before displaying the form.
Then, get the IDs from the form and insert them in the third table.

Comment: Yes This is what I originally planned to do. But how do i retrive the customer ID and product ID? I know you can use $query=mysql_query(select cid from customers)...  but then this will receive the number of row which will be 1... how do I store the VALUE of query in a variable? because then I will be able to do the INSERT query by using those variables.. i.e. INSERT INTO customerRequests $CID(this will be the result done fm the select query),$pID(the will be the result of second select query from the products table),$_POST['the other data which is collected in the form']

Comment: As thaJeztah said, don't forget that mysql_*() functions are deprecated !

Answer (score 1):

"Johnny, if you're using Dreamweaver, your insert statements needs to look like this:if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "insertForm")) { $insertSQL = sprintf(INTO CustomerRequests (productName, qty, cID) values (%s, %s, %s)" etc.

Then submit your information using a form with hidden fields, such as:
    <form name="insertForm" type="post" action="placeOrder.php">
    <input type="hidden" type="text" id="qty" value="<php? echo $row_Recordset1['qty']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" type="text" name="productName" value="<php? echo $row_Recordset1['productName']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" type="text" name="cID" value="<php? echo $cID; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="insertForm" />
    <input type="submit" name="send" id="Submit" value="Submit Form" />
    </form>

Otherwise, just forget the Dreamweaver stuff and use: insert into CustomerRequests (productName, qty, cID) values (bananas, 2, 1044) and use same hidden fields in your form. You also need to capture the data submitted in the form and save it as variables, as you have already done: $quantity=$_POST['quantity'], etc.

I had so much trouble even submitting this info because of the "code submission not being properly formatted",so I hope you get this! Change < to < and > to > to make sense of this code.
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help mate. I am not using dreamwaver :)